# Is $ST$ symmetric if $SDT$ is?

Tags: matrices

I have two square matrices $S$ and $T$ and a diagonal matrix $D$, all of the same size. If I know that $SDT$ is symmetric, can I conclude that also $ST$ is symmetric?

Comment: Do we know anything about the rank of $D$? If it is the zero matrix, then...

Comment: Have you tried something? Even when they're all invertible there are counterexamples.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  I was looking for the case of $S$ lower triangular $T$ upper triangular, with $S$, $D$, $T$ all invertible.  In such cases I always got $ST$ symmetric.  Then I tried with a general $S$ and $T$ and I got another symmetric $ST$ (maybe i tried here a particular case).  If $S$ and $T$ are lower and upper triangular and all the matrices are invertible, then is it true?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Sorry, I forgot to say $D$ invertible.  (read the comment above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $ST$ is not necessarily symmetric. For example $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&4\\1&2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}-1&2\\1&-1\end{array}\right)=I,$$ and if you omit the middle matrix, which is diagonal, you'll get a non-symmetric matrix.